# How to get "View" from a WindowManager

Tags: android

I would like to ask for help. I am designing an application that should take screenshots in a service similar to DU recorder. The problem is that I can not access the "getWindow ()" method from a service I was looking for information and I think it can be done through a WindowsManager but I have no idea how to convert a WindowsManager into a View I hope your help

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have done. It'd be easier to help you.

Comment: You do not have access to other apps' views from a service. Use the media projection APIs, available on Android 5.0 (`MediaProjectionManager`, etc.).